# How to make any element cover rest of the total area using bootstrap 4 d-flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, twitter-bootstrap-4

This structure can be created easily using bootstrap d-flex now. How am I suppose to create any area like the second image?

[image: First image]
[image: Second image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to apply `flex-grow:1` to the middle div so that it can occupy the remaining space

```css
.bd-highlight {
  background-color: rgba(86, 61, 124, .15);
  border: 1px solid rgba(86, 61, 124, .15);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="d-flex align-items-start flex-column bd-highlight" style="height: 200px;">
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight" style="flex-grow:1;">Flex item</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not flex:auto to use? Are these both same?

Comment: @HasanTareq generally the idea is here to set `flex-grow:1` to the middle div which comes in both `flex:1`(flex:1 1 0) and `flex:auto`(flex:1 1 auto)...so yes they are same if you are targeting the `flex-grow`, but actually they are not same....[**Read this**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)...answer updated...

Comment: Thanks dude! for your help